# centralizer of the order 2^k cyclic permutation matrix over F_2

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-groups

Let $C$ be the $2^k\times 2^k$-permutation matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$ of the $2^k$-cycle. We needed to know the structure of its centralizer in $\mathrm{GL}_{2^k}(\mathbb{F}_2)$, and we computed it - it was not too easy. It's an abelian group, and so we were able to compute the decomposition of the quotient of the centralizer over the subgroup generated by $C$ into the sum of cyclic subgroups, as follows. 
$$
\bigoplus_{i=2}^k (\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_{2^{k+1-i}})^{2^{i-2}}.
$$

We wonder if this was already done. (We also did this for more general case of other primes, not only 2, formulas are similar).

Update: see [centralizer of a n-cyclic permutation matrix over F_2 in GL(n,2)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140280/centralizer-of-a-n-cyclic-permutation-matrix-over-f-2-in-gln-2) for a follow-up question.

Comment: @Mark: That argument works in characteristic zero, but not here. The only eigenvalue in this case is 1.

Comment: The matrix is similar to a matrix in Jordan normal form with a single Jordan block and eigenvalue 1,so its centralizer is conjugate to the centralizer of that matrix in Jordan form.

Comment: @Geoff: You are right.

Comment: You're calculating the group of units of the group algebra ${\mathbb F}_2C$ of a cyclic group $C$ of order $2^k$ (your matrix describes how a generator of $C$ acts on the regular representation, and so the centralizer is the group of units in $\operatorname{End}_{{\mathbb F}_2C}({\mathbb F}_2C)\cong\mathbb{F}_2C$). In this guise, it's calculated in Prop. XI(5.7) of Bass's Algebraic K-Theory.

Comment: There is a paper by S. H. Murray, Conjugacy classes in Maximal Parabolic Subgroups of General Linear Groups, J. Algebra 233, 135-155 (2000). In Section 4 (Centralizers in general linear groups) he works out the centralizers of arbitrary elements in $GL_n(k)$.

Comment: Murray's paper doesn't really give you a closed form answer, as far as I can see, but Prop. XI(5.7) of Bass indeed does.
I wonder if the more general case of $2^km$-cycle, for $m$ odd, has been done before (We also have a result for this case too).

Comment: here I asked a more general question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140280/centralizer-of-a-n-cyclic-permutation-matrix-over-f-2-in-gln-2

Comment: There must be a misprint in your formula, since we get no factor $(\mathbb{Z}/2^k)$. The result in Bass yields the formula $\bigoplus_{i=1}^k (\mathbb{Z}/2^i)^{2^{k-i}}$.

Comment: oops, indeed, the formula I gave is for the quotient of the centralizer over $\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}$. I'll update the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the details of our computation can now be found in http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.0113